# Getting value of JavaScript var and assigning it's value to a PHP variable in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I have implemented a simple HTML5 game onto my website. Here is the game I have implemented: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery.

As you can see the link above, within the canvas, there is a score. What I want to do is get the (highest) score of the user.

Let me break it down:

- Conor is logged in, and has Alice and Anderson as his friends.
- Conor plays the snake game and gets a score of 6.
- Now, I want the score of 6 to be assigned to a PHP var so that I can `INSERT` that variable into the database in order to make a high score list and display the scores on the same page.

I have a file called `snake.js` which contains all the JavaScript from the link. The javascript file is called on the main page- `snake_game.php`.

I have limited experience using JavaScript and I am unsure how to approach this issue.

Comment: You should to use AJAX to send a JS variable to a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You want the XMLHttpRequest object, this is a pretty basic AJAX question:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Send the info as an encoded string in the post body, then use PHPs global $_POST to grab that information.  Escape the string or use a prepared statement (better) and use that to write a query that updates the table.